# CSS: Bevel border with gradient?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a perfect bevel border using CSS.

Basically, I need the border to be raised a bit and have a gradient colour.

The issue that I have is that I am using `border-style:ridge;` as that is the closest i could find but the colours/gradient is not really good and the bevel style is not that good either.

there is a line on the corners with radius where the lighter colour meets the darker colour!

This is a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mm7x2x67/1/)

Is there any better way to do this using CSS?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the css code:

```
.ttle{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 4px solid #c2924e;
    border-style: ridge;
    width:100%;
height:auto;
padding:10px;
min-height:150px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 3em;
border-top-right-radius: 3em;
background-color:#000;
position:relative;
    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Frankly, I'd use an SVG.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I would use SVG if the content of the div which are texts were not dynamic.

Comment: @Paulie_D, can you please point me in a right direction on how to use SVG in this  example?

Comment: isn't that just tutorials on how to use SVG and not how to scale the height of the SVG based on the content?

Comment: shadow can give some effects too https://jsfiddle.net/nL4t9jLw/1/ https://jsfiddle.net/nL4t9jLw/2/ ( example mix of gradients and shadows http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EKdJOE & http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/Awtvi )

Comment: I don't know why someone would downvote this.  It seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a gradient border, you can accomplish a cleaner border effect using an inner div and gradient backgrounds on the outer div. That should give you the desired effect. Keep in mind with that radius you have going there, the inner radius will need to decrease slightly to keep the width of the "border" consistent across it.  You may need to play with this slightly across browsers. Tested on Chrome & FF / Mac.

https://jsfiddle.net/treetop1500/nL4t9jLw/

```css
.ttle {
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c2924e, #7c5b2d);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#c2924e, #7c5b2d);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#c2924e, #7c5b2d);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#c2924e, #7c5b2d);
  /* Standard syntax */
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3em;
  border-top-right-radius: 3em;
  background-color: #000;
}
.inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 150px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2.8em;
  border-top-right-radius: 2.8em;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="ttle">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="title">
</div>

.title { 
border:5px solid #FC0;
display: inline-block;
padding: .5em 2em .55em;
-webkit-border-radius: .5em; 
-moz-border-radius: .5em;
border-radius: .5em;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```